# appointment booking -jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jqtouch, appointment

I am building a mobile website using jquery/ html5 and need a appointment booking functionality so customers can make an appointment booking. The customer selects the service they want then selects the practioner and then it checks the availability and displays possible free time over the next week

a site which does exactly what i want is instant-scheduling.com

i have thought about using
https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

would it be possible to rework the interface so that rather than selecting a time and duration you select the service and then provider and it displays the available times

what other possibilities are there to achieve this

Comment: Shouldn't be hard. Gonna work on this now since i need for a client the same thing. I'll let you know when i finished.